# Programmable QR scanner is needed

Tags: scanner

I am new in hardware so I hope this is the right place to ask such questions.

For one of my software projects, I want to add a QR scanner that able to makes POST requests to the server over WIFI. It has to be programmable because only specific information from QR code has to be retrieved. QR code will be changing every 2 seconds and scanned from mobile devices all the time. Not expensive since I might need over 50 devices. I knew Python a bit, so maybe the device should support that language.

Also, I would like to mount it to the wall.

Something similar to the one the picture would be ideal

[image]

I would be thankful for any direct link or hints on how to search by myself.

Comment: Look into using a tablet with front facing camera. This will offer you a lot more options. I have seen places with this type of sign in system.